# What is the difference between storing documents in azure blob as file and storing it in base64?

Tags: azure, base64, azure-blob-storage

I want to know the difference between storing documents in blob storage as file and storing it in base64 format in azure blob storage.

I am storing my documents in azure blob storage. I am storing all documents as files and not converting it to base64.

I want to know the advantages of converting file into base64 before uploading it to container.

Can you please please provide me the link to any refrence documents.

I know that base64 takes less space than actual files. I want to understand it in detail.

Thank you..

Comment: Where are you storing the documents in base64 format? You need some kind of storage for that as well. Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: I am using Azure Blob storage.

Comment: Can you show the code or process you are using for each?

Comment: *I know that base64 takes less space than actual files* - I don't know anything about azure blob storage, but the size of a base64 encoded string is 33% greater than the data it encodes.

Comment: @jps, is it same for all types files? I got to know that the encoded base64 is 33% gratater for images. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: base64 doesn't know any filetypes, it just encodes bytes. So if you base64 encode 1kByte, the result is 1.33kB.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.